# A limit involving the gamma function

Tags: integration, limits

The limit is $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{2^{n/2}}\gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^\infty e^{-t/2} t^{n/2-1}\,dt$$

I am trying to compare it with the gamma function but I am unable to do anything useful.

Comment: How did you come across this limit?

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @kittyl thanx for advice . This question was asked by my friend & its from previous year's test paper .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Using a very minor change of variable (I let it to you), let us start with $$I=\int e^{-t/2} t^{n/2-1}\,dt=-2^{n/2}\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right)$$ which leads to  $$J=\int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^\infty e^{-t/2} t^{n/2-1}\,dt=2^{n/2} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+\sqrt{2n}}{2} \right)$$ provided $\Im\left(n+\sqrt{2n} \right)\neq 0\lor n>0$.

At this point I suppose that the problem is instead $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{2^{n/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) }\int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^\infty e^{-t/2} t^{n/2-1}\,dt$$